# Find out who or what is using API Calls?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We've just regained access to an old app.

Every 3 days, the API usage shoots up to around 150% of our limit using:
GET {page-id}

My question, are there any tools out there that I can accurately see where this call is taking place? A website or what page-ID is being called even?

Something to help us narrow down and cut down usage where we're otherwise having difficulty finding it.

Comment: No, that is not available. Keeping track on that detail level would be your app’s own responsibility. Depending on what kind of app, you might want to tighten your app settings to exclude the possibility that someone else might be using tokens belonging to your app for their own requests somehow.

Comment: without knowing what the app does, it´s nearly impossible to help you. maybe you´re not caching things server side?

Comment: Oh we definitely cache things server side, but we own thousands of sites and a dozen or so servers and not all of them use this APP ID let alone actually use facebook at all. So we're having difficulty finding those sites. 

Definitely our fault for not keeping track. Don't think we would ever have thought we'd need this level of detail of usage. 

Will just need to search each server for the ID the slow way I guess. 

Thanks guys!